# How to disable warnings for workbox-webpack-plugin for generated service worker

Tags: webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox-webpack-plugin

I use **GenerateSw** class for my worker generation.
It works fine, but i need to precache some resources that not handled by webpack for offline page, so i use:

```
additionalManifestEntries: [
    '/offline',
    'https://static.express/img/laksjhdaskldfjlaljsafsp/connection-lost.svg'
]
```

but i'm facing this warnings, even though **mode** property is set to **prod**.
[image]

**Question: Can i hide them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid these warnings by switching to objects with `url:` properties, and `revision: null` properties for each, to indicate that they are already uniquely revisioned based on their URLs.

```
additionalManifestEntries: [
  {url: '/offline', revision: null},
  {url: 'https://static.express/img/.../connection-lost.svg', revision: null},
]
```

But... if you do that, and your URLs don't actually contain any unique revision information in them, then your users will end up "stuck" with an old copy of, e.g., `/offline` indefinitely, even when you make changes to `/offline` and redeploy. That's why Workbox makes it "hard" to do this.

A better approach for caching additional URLs is to set up a runtime caching route that will use a specific strategy on them, and potentially "warm" that strategy cache using [these techniques](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes#warm_strategy_cache). Using, e.g., a `StaleWhileRevalidate` strategy for those URLs will ensure that they will eventually be updated.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!
"Warming strategy" sounds cool, but as i understood, only files that are loaded while routing can pass to this strategy. 
Offline page will never be accessed, until there is no connection, thats why i need to pre-cache.

Comment: With "warming," you pre-populate your runtime caches during the service worker's `install` step. This is very similar to what would happen when using `workbox-precaching`,  except you'll rely on the runtime strategy to keep the resource up to date, instead of a precache manifest.